# How can I find the form name of the previous form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dialogue window (just a form) class which can be called by several forms. I want the title of this dialogue to change dependent on which form called it.

Is there a way, within the dialogue class, of finding out the form name of the form which called it (without altering the code of the several forms which can call it)?

Comment: If you called the dialog by passing the owner like this: `dialog.ShowDialog(owner);` you can use `Owner.Title` in your dialog.

Comment: @PeterBons This does require altering the code of several forms which the OP did not want, BUT if the call is not like this than he should alter it anyway since this is the only correct way to call a dialog form

Comment: Have you tried Form.ActiveForm on the dialogform before it becomes active ?

Comment: @GuidoG Since the OP doesn't tell how he calls the dialogs we cannot tell whether he needs to change the calling code :-). He might be passing the owner already.

Comment: @PeterBons Yes I agree, that is why I wrote "but if the call is not like this"

Comment: My bad, didn't read well enough :-)

Comment: Just set title of the form when you create it. `var f = new Form1(); f.Text="Something"; f.ShowDialog();`

Comment: That would need to change the calling forms, which OP does not want to @RezaAghaei

Comment: @Pikoh I see. But I think they should use such solution. At least if they don't want to pass exactly the `Text`,  they can pass a value like `Name` of the caller or something which they want to use to create `Text` based on it, something like `var f = new Form1(this.Name);`. It's just adding another constructor to the `DIalog` and a `Find/ReplaceAll`  for usages of `Form1`.

Comment: If OP can change the calling forms, it would be better to just call `ShowDialog(this)` as some comments had already said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it just with a simple example, but using [GetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx) you can get the parent form of your dialog. 
First of all you have to add this definitions in your dialog:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex);

public enum GWL
{
    GWL_WNDPROC = (-4),
    GWL_HINSTANCE = (-6),
    GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8),
    GWL_STYLE = (-16),
    GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20),
    GWL_USERDATA = (-21),
    GWL_ID = (-12)
}
```

And then,in your dialog, you can do this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr parentHandle = GetWindowLongPtr(this.Handle, GWL.GWL_HWNDPARENT);
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {   
        if (frm.Handle==parentHandle)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(frm.Name); //this is your parent form
        }

    }
}
```

Anyway, I think it's easier to just call `ShowDialog(this)`, but if you can't really change the calling forms, this method may be handy.

Comment: this works but there is a much easier way to get the parent form, see my answer I put here one hour earlier

Comment: @GuidoG so? What does it matter you answer an hour earlier than me? The answers are completly different. BTW, now that you say it, my answer works. I've just tried yours and does not work for me. `Form.ActiveForm;` is always null in my sample application.

Comment: It does not matter when it was posted. My answer works for me I have tested in MDI and non MDI. So if it is not working for you than what type of application is your sample application ?

Answer (score 0):

FormCollection may help you:

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(frm.Name.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Imagine, that you have **10** open forms (the dialog included), and the dialog has been popped up from the **5th one**. How come you detect the form of interest (`Application.OpenForms[4]`)? You can easily enumerate all the open forms, but then you have to filter out the required form and this is the main difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did consider the OpenForms property however, as Dmitry points out, I need to locate the actual form name which called this dialogue when multiple forms might be open.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on the dialogform, make sure you do this before the dialogform becomes active to prevent it from finding itself.

```
public Form GetActiveForm()
{
    Form activeForm = Form.ActiveForm;

    if (activeForm.IsMdiContainer && activeForm.ActiveMdiChild != null)
    {
        activeForm = activeForm.ActiveMdiChild;
    }
    return activeForm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that You are creating other dialogs(forms) from the main form, You can do:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    //Some code
    public void OpenDialog_Click(...)
    {
        MyOtherForm form = new MyOtherForm();
        form.Parent = this;
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And Your 2nd form:

```
public partial class MyOtherForm : Form
{
    public MyOtherForm()
    {
        var parent = this.Parent as Form;
        if(parent != null)
            this.Title = parent.Title;
    }
}
```